# How can I get the number of days in a year using JodaTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
new Period(Years.ONE).getDays();

new Period(1, 0, 0, 000).getDays();
```

The answer I want is obviously 365.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the real number of days for a given year:

```
int year = 2012;
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(year,1,1);
System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(ld,ld.plusYears(1)).getDays());
```

Of course, this returns 365 or 366... normally:

```
int year = 1582;
LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(year,1,1,GJChronology.getInstance());
System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(ld,ld.plusYears(1)).getDays());
// year 1582 had 355 days
```

Comment: This should also work: `(new LocalDate(year, 12, 31)).getDayOfYear();`

Answer (score 12):

The answer you want isn't obviously `365`. It is either `365` or `366`, you don't take into account leap years in your example.

Detecting a leap year and just hard coding it with a ternary statement would be unacceptable for some reason?

```
final DateTime dt = new DateTime();
final int daysInYear = dt.year().isLeap() ? 366 : 365;
```

Of course this would give you the number of days in the current year, how to get number of days in a different year is trivial and a exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Year.of( 2017 ).length()
```

## Using java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

The [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class can represent any particular year.

```
Year year = Year.of( 2017 );
```

You may interrogate for information about that year such as its length in number of days or whether it a [Leap Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) or not.

```
int countDaysInYear = year.length() ;
boolean isLeapYear = year.isLeap() ; // ISO proleptic calendar system rules.
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

new DateTime().year().toInterval().toDuration().getStandardDays();