# Is there any single line java command using joda to get seconds in a year?

Tags: java, jodatime, seconds

Is there any single line java command using joda to get seconds in a year?

I tried various combinations but not seems to be working.

What I tried is

```
    System.out.println("Seconds in a day: " + Days.ONE.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```

Comment: Seconds in a year can change. See `DateTimeConstants`.

Comment: Exactly it can change Sotirios.  I need standard seconds only :).  I am using it to set cookie life and that ok for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking on stackoverflow and come across this 
[How can I get the number of days in a year using JodaTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282419/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-days-in-a-year-using-jodatime)

got the idea

```
new DateTime().year().toInterval().toDuration().getStandardSeconds()
```

and it works for me.